# Ideal laptop power user network setup - Systemd-networkd bridge versus libvirt bridge

Tags: libvirt, systemd-networkd

Under linux we have several ways to configure a network card.

Since I'm a simple advanced user with virtual machine needs, and for reasons of homogeneity, I try to simplify and use systemd as much as possible.

And so I don't understand why we have on ubuntu or debian, devices created by libvirt.

1. What is the advantage for me and why not use a systemd bridge?
2. Can you help me refine a typical configuration please?

For my needs, I hope:

- if I'm at home (SSID=MyHomeNetwork), bond0 as the main network card; to have the same ip whether I am under wifi or under rj45 and not have any IP conflict.
- Outside my home, I want Networkmanager to take over since unfortunately systemd-network has no desktop mechanism..
- permanently an available bridge network card for the needs of my systemd-nspawn and KVM

`networkctl`

> IDX LINK         TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
> 1 lo           loopback carrier     unmanaged
> 2 rj45          ether    enslaved    configured
> 3 wifi         wlan     no-carrier  unmanaged
> 4 bond0        bond     routable    configured
> 5 virbr0       bridge   no-carrier  unmanaged

## Configuration for Home only with the help of bonding

/etc/systemd/network/30-bond0.netdev

```bash
[NetDev]
Name=bond0
Kind=bond

[Bond]
Mode=active-backup
PrimaryReselectPolicy=always
MIIMonitorSec=1s
```

/etc/systemd/network/30-bond0.netdev

```bash
[Match]
Name=bond0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[Link]
MACAddress=ff:ff:ff:a1:a2:a3
```

/etc/systemd/network/30-ethernet-bond0.network

```bash
[Match]
Name=rj45

[Network]
Bond=bond0
PrimarySlave=true
```

/etc/systemd/network/30-wifi-bond0.network

```bash
[Match]
Name=wifi
SSID=MyHomeNetwork

[Network]
Bond=bond0
```

1. difficulty 1: when I start the pc, the wifi and the RJ45 start at the same time and I have to deactivate them to leave bond0 alone and up.
2. difficulty 2: the fallback mechanism to NetworkManager is missing

## Substitute configuration for virtualization under systemd-network

3. difficulty 3: is missing for the moment 0:)